# JQuery JSON push using object as key

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object, key

I am trying to write a JSON file using JQuery. I am attempting to use a javascript object as a json key however it does not run. My code is:

```
var lvl = 2;
$.getJSON( "json/levels.json", function(levels) {
    levels.level.push({
        lvl:[{
            "Test": "some text"
        }] 
    }
);
```

This outputs:

```
{
    "level": [{
        "lvl": [{
            "Test": "Some Text",
        }]
    }]
}
```

However, it should be returning:

```
{
    "level": [{
        "2": [{
            "Test": "Some Text",
        }]
    }]
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks
Nick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use the value of the variable as the key of an object, try this:

```
$.getJSON( "json/levels.json", function(levels) {
    var obj = {};
    obj[lvl] = [{ "Test": "some text" }];
    levels.level.push(obj);
);
```

Comment: You can use Identifiers, string literals and number literals in an object literal.

Comment: Note that ECMAScript 6 allows computed keys in object literals. `{[lvl]: "foo"}`